# Renaming worksheet gives 'Out of Memory'; CurrentRegion property fails

Tags: excel, vba, out-of-memory

My employer has recently upgraded from

Excel 2013 (15.0.4805.1001) 
MSO (15.0.4919.1002) 32-bit to Excel for Office 365 MSO (16.0.11328.20362) 32-bit

There are no active add-ins (other than referred to below when loaded).

An Excel add-in (xlam) that I have created no longer functions correctly.

The add-in works with an open workbook and formats a lot of 'raw' data as tables (listobjects) and creates a number of PivotTables and Charts in a dashboard-style layout. During the process some blank sheets are copied from the add-in to the open workbook, and renamed as required.

For the most part, everything works fine (pivots created, dashboard created). At the end of the process I create an index sheet by copying a blank sheet from the add-in, and re-naming it (as ...Index). This is where things go wrong. Excel just seemed to 'hang'. On investigation I discovered that the sheet was not being renamed (so further processing stopped).

Delving into this further with error-trapping turned off, if I try to rename the sheet using the immediate window, I get

> run-time error 7 Out of Memory

Further, if I manually rename the sheet (Excel interface) and then set the code running from that point, I've discovered that I can't use the `CurrentRegion` property (some sorting is done on the newly inserted sheet). Any attempt to use `CurrentRegion` results in

> Unable to get the CurrentRegion property of the Range Class

This also applies to using the immediate window on ANY open workbook (e.g. `?Activesheet.range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)`

These errors persist during the current session of Excel (that is, I can create a blank workbook and try to rename a sheet using VBA but get an error; manually renaming a tab is OK). If I restart Excel everything is fine.

I require to use some global/public variables but (given that everything worked in Excel 2013) can't see that these would be the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After a further couple of hours looking into this, I established that the error was related in some way to a module which added slicers to the dashboard. The slicers were, in fact added (and stepping through the code no errors were generated).

Adding the slicers in a slightly different fashion appears to have got around the problem, although I am still none the wiser as to why it actually occurred in the first place (the original code for the slicers worked fine in Excel 2013).